# LINQ Query with submodel passed into View renders creates duplicate elements in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm getting unwanted duplicate items rendered on "Display" view, it is only happening with blogIDs that have more than one commentID.
As each blogID can have many commentIDs relationship. When I select a blogID it then displays duplicate items of the following blogTitle, blogauthor, slider-image, subheading, blogContent.

I believe this has something to do with the foreach iteration of going over my model twice due to the additional commentIDs associated with that blogID.

I'm trying to get this work with using Comments as a sub model in BlogViewModel, but this maybe the underlying cause of duplicate values displayed.

```
  public IActionResult Display(int bp)
        {
            

            var blogResult = from a in _db.Users
                             join b in _db.blog on a.Id equals b.userID where b.blogID == bp
                             join c in _db.comment on b.blogID equals c.blogID
                             select new BlogViewModel {
                                 blogID = b.blogID,
                                 blogTitle = b.blogTitle,
                                 blogContent = b.blogContent,
                                 userID = a.Id, 
                                 publishedDate = b.publishedDate,
                                 firstName = a.firstName,
                                 lastName = a.lastName,
                                 Comments = new CommentModel { comment = c.comment, commentID = c.commentID, reply = c.reply, blogID = b.blogID, userID = c.userID }
                                 };
                                

            return View(blogResult.ToList());
        }
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<AVI_IT.ViewModels.BlogViewModel>

<div class="container">

    @foreach (var v in Model)
    {
        <h1 class="blogTitle">@v.blogTitle</h1>
        <p id="blogAuthor">@v.firstName | @v.publishedDate</p>
        <img src="~/images/slider-img3.png" id="blogImage" />
        <p class="subHeading">SubHeading</p>
        <p id="blogContent">
            @v.blogContent
        </p>

    }


    @*for user commenting*@

    <hr />
    <h4 class="commentHeading">Leave a Comment</h4>
    <div class="row p-3"><input class="btn btn-success" action="submit" value="Post" /></div>
    <hr />
    <h4 class="commentHeading">All Comments</h4>

    <div id="allComments">
        <div class="row p-3">
            <div class="col-2">

                <div class="card" style="width: 500px;background-color: lightslategrey; margin:20px 0 0 0;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        @foreach (var test in Model)
                        {
                            @test.Comments.userID
                            <h5 class="card-title">@test.Comments.userID</h5>
                            <div class="col-10 p-4">
                                <p class="card-text">
                                    @test.Comments.comment
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Model

```
 public class BlogViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int blogID { get; set; }

        public string blogTitle { get; set; }
        public string blogContent { get; set; }
        public string userID { get; set; }

        public DateTime publishedDate { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        //Wrap CommentModel in this model, so we can use two models in razor view
        public CommentModel Comments { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: The duplicate are occurring when you have more than one a or b with same ID.  If you have two items a with id 123 and two items b with 123 you will get four rows in results.

Comment: `Distinct` may be of interest.

Comment: @jdweng ok, so it appears that the solution would be to take Comments outside of this model. Unless there is another way around it? That means Ill have to have another way to use two models in one view

Comment: Usually I do a GroupBy  on results to remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

**

You Can Use Group By to Remove Duplication of records. and you use    two model.

**